# Time complexity of dependent and conditional triple for-loop

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

```
for i in xrange(1,n+1):
    for j in xrange(1,i*i):
        if j%i==0:
            for k in xrange(0,j):
                print("*")
```

What will be the time complexity of the above algorithm?

Comment: This is a question from my past exam.. after anlyzing I was able to find out that the statement 3 will hold true for 'n' times only..  by this we can deduce that the 5th statement will run atmost n**3 times.. shouldn't it be O(n^3)?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a homework problem, but is very interesting so I'll take a shot. We will just count number of times that asterisk is printed, because it dominates.

For each `j`, only those that are divisible by `i` trigger the execution of the innermost loop. How many of them are there? Well, in range `[1, i*i)` those are `i, 2*i, 3*i, ..., (i-1)*i`. Let's go further. `k` iterates from `0` to `j`, so first we will have `i` iterations (for `j=i`), then `2*i` (for `j=2*i`), then `3*i`.. until we iterate `(i-1)*i` times. This is a total of `i + 2*i + 3*i + (i-1)*i` printed asterisks **for each `i`**. Since `i` goes from `0` to `n`, total number of iterations is sum of all `i + 2*i + 3*i + (i-1)*i` where `i` goes from `0` to `n`. Let's sum it up:

[image]

Here we used multiple times the formula for sum of first `n` numbers. The factor which dominates in the final sum is obviously `k^3`, and since the formula for sum of first `n-1` cubes is

[image],

the total complexity is `O(n^4)`.

Comment: Have a look at the above comment .

Comment: Actually I am currently online via mobile .. so I am not able to describe well .. have a look at the comment above ..  I think that it should be O(n**3) .. I will explain that to you more effectively later today.

Comment: @AbhishekKhandelwal I have written you every line of the proof that this is `O(n^4)`, please examine it more carefully. And if you still don't feel convinced, try to count the number of executions for e.g. `n` and `3n` for sufficiently large `n`. You will notice that the ratio is close to 81. You can do the same for arbitrary `n` and `kn`, you will is that the ratio is close to `k^4`.

Comment: @AbhishekKhandelwal I expanded my answer further, hopefully now is more clear how to get total number of iterations, which gives `O(n^4)` complexity.

Comment: But my colleague is confident that the complexity is O(n^5) . But I am not able to understand why. Can you please describe me why is he saying O(n^5 ).

Comment: @AbhishekKhandelwal How could I know why he is saying that this is `O(n^5)`? :) Can you find an error in my reasoning? Above is a rather extensive proof that this is `O(n^4)` and your first comment was "I think it should be `O(n^3)`", and now you are claiming "my colleague is confident that the complexity is `O(n^5)`". This is **not** the way how problems should be solved. Math and computer science are based on rigorous proofs. If you find an error in my proof, I would be happy to correct it, but it seems that it the proof is complete and correct.

Comment: A colleague of mine is saying that he read somewhere that in worst case we do not consider the if statements .. we only consider break and exit statements and he is pretty confident that the ans is O(n^5). He says this is a simulation and I need proper mathematical proof.

Comment: @AbhishekKhandelwal Exactly, and a proof is written in my answer. If your colleague thinks different, invite him to post an answer here.

Comment: @AbhishekKhandelwal Did you get exam results? What does it say about this question? :)