# Time complexity verification

Tags: time-complexity

So I have this block of code:

```
int sum=0;
for (int i=1; i<n; ++i){
    for (int j=1; j<i*i; ++j){
        if (j%i==0){
            for (int k=0; k<j; ++k){
                ++sum;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I figured this has a $O(n^5)$ complexity. I tried timing this to verify it but I couldn't tell if the best fit was of $n^4$ or $n^5$.

Comment: Exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46562623/time-complexity-of-this-algo

Answer (score 0):

The complexity is n^4.
The reason is that the third for will run `O(n^2)` times instead of `O(n^3)` as you may have calculated. The if case will only be called `(i*i)^(1/2) = O(n)` times for each step of the outer for, because the number of multiples of `i` from `1` to `i*i` is exactly `i = O(n)`.

So I have this block of code:

```
int sum=0;
for (int i=1; i<n; ++i){
    for (int j=1; j<i*i; ++j){          // O(n)
        if (j%i==0){
            for (int k=0; k<j; ++k){    // O(n^2)
                ++sum;                  // O(n^4)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't agree with this answer

Comment: I'm having trouble following your logic. Why is the if-case called O(n) times?

Comment: I'm very bad in explaining things, let me edit my answer. The if is called O(n) times for each step of the outer for.